# Open source Alfresco

Tags: java, content-management-system, customization, alfresco

Hi I am new to Alfresco I have installed enterprise edition of Alfresco but I guess its 30 days trial only and only for evaluation purpose. I have three question.

1. Is alfresco available in free version or not ?
2. Alfresco is Content management or Document management ?
3. Can I customize Alfresco to build any time of web application e.g Shopping Cart, Library Management, Job Portal. If answer is yes then how difficult it would be ?

Just like Joomla(PHP CMS) there are millions of installer, we need to download the installer and install the module and your entire application will be converted to your choice e.g Shopping Cart, Library Management, Job Portal within a minute with minimum effort.

Comment: I think all your questions could be answered by the products info pages. Please consider that [Stack Overflow is not a proxy for customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/143302) and questions like this do not fit the Q&A format.

Comment: Alfresco is a Free/Libre enterprise content management system for Microsoft Windows and Unix-like operating systems. refer 'http://www.alfresco.com/'

Comment: Thanks for comment and I will remember to ask only specific question in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is a free version called "Community" version: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_and_Install_Alfresco
2. Alfresco is an ECM system (Enterprise CONTENT Management)
3. You could use Alfresco to develop any type of application you want, but I wouldn't suggest that. For most of the time you would be complicating things to do stuff that's way easier to do with other systems/frameworks. Alfresco a platform intended to be used for building content rich sofware on top it. So if your application is not about content and content management I wouldn't suggest using Alfresco.

(Point 3. is just my oppinion!)

Comment: Thanks for help i do install the community version but it says Evaluation use only. Well i am trying to get answer from alfresco customer support.

Comment: I wish to stop this thread because its going to volatile the stackover flow "ask question rule".